# How to hide navbar on scroll of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, uikit

I've read every stackoverflow thread looking for a solution on the subject but I can't seem to get it to work. The default iOS implementation using "navigationController.hidesBaronSwipe" works just one-way. That is, it hides the navbar when I scroll but disappears and doesn't unhide when I scroll the other direction. Below is a screenshot of my code and auto layout constraints as suggested by other developers on stack overflow. [tableview constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNqGx.png)

```
class TaskVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


var tasks: [Task] = [

    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 24, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 25, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task",   coins: 26, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 24, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 25, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task",   coins: 26, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 24, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 25, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task",   coins: 26, houseMate: "David"),
    Task(title: "This is a Test Task", coins: 24, houseMate: "David")

]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    tableview.dataSource = self
    
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    
    //The below code registers the custom tableviewcell created using Nib
    
    tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
    
    
}
```

[image: tableview constraints]

Comment: A UITableView is a UIScrollView, do you can use scrollView delegate methods to handle this.

Comment: I have tried the delegate methods but it seems there's something always wrong with my constraints because it hides when I scroll but never unhides.